# MySQL inserting with select max(`Column`)+1 on possibly empty results

Tags: mysql, select, insert

I've seen a lot of questions along the same-ish lines as mine, but they're just not quite exactly the same issue as me.

Here's my query:

```
insert into`quotes`(`QuoteID`,`QuoteRequestID`,`Number`,`UserID`,`Viewed`,
    `_Latest`)
select uuid(),uuid(),
ifnull(max(`quotes`.`Number`),0)+1,'Some User ID',1,1 
from`quotes`
join`quoterequests`using(`QuoteRequestID`)
where`quoterequests`.`UserID`='Some User Other ID';
```

And this is the error I'm getting:

> Error Code: 1048. Column 'QuoteID' cannot be null

So my guess is that the select statement isn't returning anything, but how can that be since I'm using `max()` in my query?

Sure enough, if I remove the `insert` part and just run the select statement by itself, then I do get the expected results, with the new UUIDs (definitely not a null value) and all. What is happening here? Is this a bug with MySQL? My MySQL version is 5.7.14;

---

**EDIT**

So I have figured out if I wrap the select in another select, it now works as expected. Not sure if that's a solution or a workaround though, but it did get my query working.

Comment: Your query return   a row with  null value in  uuid() function  ...  check for uuid() FUNCTION

Comment: @scaisEdge the uuid() function definitely does not return null, it's a built in function to return unique identifiers. Plus I specified in the body of the post that I checked the output of the select statement without the insert and I got the results I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you might have some trigger which generates the error - that is the only explanation I can think about.

Comment: There are no triggers on any of the tables in the query